# k8s Resource Quotas definition

Tags: kubernetes

I want to ignore the resource request that is defined in the service manifest:

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "512Mi"
    cpu: "500m"
  limits:
    memory: "1024Mi"
    cpu: "1000m"
```

because sometimes developers specifies requests more than they need, and it causes other services to not have enough resources.

I read about Resource Quotas, which I need to define at the namespace level.

My question is: If I define Resource Quotas in the namespace, will the resource request at the service be considered? ignored? or anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can use here is a `ResourceQuota` something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: mem-cpu
spec:
  hard:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "100Mi"
    requests.cpu: "500m"
    requests.memory: "512Mi"
    limits.cpu: "1"
    limits.memory: 1Gi
```

So if you have defined the resource quota (the value which cannot be exceeded by sum of cpu & memory requests respectively) in a namespace to 500m cpu & 512Mi of memory and you worry a single pod might take it up all, you can also define `cpu` & `memory` resources in the `ResourceQuota` (as you see in the example above).

A pod with resource requests:

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: "512Mi"
    cpu: "500m"
  requests:
    memory: "200Mi"
    cpu: "200m"
```

will result in an error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "so2.yaml": pods "quota-mem-cpu-demo" is forbidden: exceeded quota: mem-cpu, requested: cpu=200m,memory=200Mi, used: cpu=0,memory=0, limited: cpu=100m,memory=100Mi
```

While this would work:

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: "512Mi"
    cpu: "500m"
  requests:
    memory: "100Mi"
    cpu: "100m"
```

So you can control what resources a user requests.

Comment: in the first manifest, what is the "hard" key? Is it defined in the namespace level?

Comment: The `ResourceQuota` object is applied on a namespace. Users create resources (pods, services, etc.) in the namespace, and this tracks usage to ensure it does not exceed hard resource limits defined in a ResourceQuota. So it applies a hard limit and not preferential. For further reading: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/

Comment: @I.zv Does this provide the answers you were looking for your question(s)?

Comment: Yes, I am also wondering, is it possible to define resources without the requests section? (requests:  limits: memory:512Mi cpu:500m)

Comment: @I.zv If that's the case, consider marking it as the answer so it's helpful to others too. As for your question, I don't understand what you mean. Please raise it as a separate question with all the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.  Here is the new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67046346/k8d-define-resources-withouts-requests

Answer (score 0):

> If I define Resource Quotas in the namespace, will the resource request at the service be considered? ignored? or anything else?

As said in the name, this is a **Quota**, meaning that the team using the namespace can use *up to* that quota, but no more. As explained in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/), this is enforced at *creation time*. When a Resource Quota is set, users are *required* to define resources in the manifests:

> If quota is enabled in a namespace for compute resources like cpu and memory, users must specify requests or limits for those values; otherwise, the quota system may reject pod creation.

> Hint: Use the LimitRanger admission controller to force defaults for pods that make no compute resource requirements.

Comment: Thanks. Take the scenario where I defined quota in the namespace to 500m cpu and 100Mib memory. Then, inside the service manifest, developer-a set resource request to 500m and 100Mib (developer-a isn't aware of the quota), while the service actually needs only 10m and 10Mib. Then, if developer-b wants to create a service with resource request, he won't be able to because there are no enough resources thanks to developer-a.
Then... how Quotas help in my situation?

Comment: What if I used LimitRange? do you think it will serve my needs better?

Comment: You can use `LimitRange` object to define default values similar to `cpu` & `memory` resources in a `ResourceQuota` object. Any pod which doesn't specify requests (and/or limits) for those values, the default values in `LimitRange` will be applied for those.